# Probability of labelling people in a lineup

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rd-yH8hzTLs), in which a "professional astrologer" is tasked with matching up people with their star signs.

(Spoiler alert!) At around the 5:30 mark, 4 of the 12 participants reveal that their star sign was correctly identified.

This leads to the question:
**What is the probability of him getting 4 or more star signs correct, and can this be nicely generalised to getting $x$ or more correct answers out of a possible $y$ people?**

Note that each of the twelve participants have a different star sign, and so do each of the 12 cards.

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538744/correctly-labelling-people-in-a-lineup) - coincidentally inspired by the same series - however, this focuses on the expected value rather than the general probability.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Not an explicit answer, but some references.

What you're looking for is $X = $the number of *fixed points in a random permutation*.  (I.e. if the astrologer guesses a random permutation, how many would he/she guess correctly?)

The distribution of $X$ can be obtained via the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  Here is one reference that includes the formula for $P(X = k)$:

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheNumberOfFixedPointsInARandomPermutation/

And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics contains a ton more details on related problems, but AFAICT not the explicit formula.